# TinyMCE with angular height 100% not working

Tags: angular, tinymce

Adding TinyMCE to my project and cant get the height to fill the page.  Here is my html page, just a simple full screen div with the editor inside:

```
<div class="page-layout blank p-24" fusePerfectScrollbar>
    <editor
        apiKey="8zpue1x5ae105wdqusojcbzo6vov9mpymvixyf4375qv9mfk"
        [init]="{
            menubar: false,
            resize: true,
            height: '100%',
            min_height: 350,
            plugins: [
                'advlist autolink lists link image imagetools imagecharmap preview anchor',
                'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                'insertdatetime media table paste code'
            ],
            toolbar:
                'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
                alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
                bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | image'
            }"
    ></editor>

</div>
```

But when it loads it starts out as if I set the height to 0 until I try to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

With your code the height of editor tag is assigned to the iframe that will be created in the editor component. Now, the editor tag is not taking the height of the enclosing div, so you are not seeing the height that you wanted.

Add style="height: 100%;" to the editor tag, then it will have the height of enclosing div and then iframe will have the height of enclosing editor tag.